# Build issue with xcode 14.3 while archive for release an IPA [iOS][Flutter]

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

## I tried to upgrade xcode 14.2 to 14.3 facing issue while archive a build for release on test flight. Attaching error below

```
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/akash/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dzpknbtessbfrlebffizodpgatsq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/qa/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-qa-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-30BD5709278C26D325FB2C8E.sh (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    cd /Users/akash/Mobile/ios
    /bin/sh -c /Users/akash/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dzpknbtessbfrlebffizodpgatsq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/qa/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-qa-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-30BD5709278C26D325FB2C8E.sh

mkdir -p /Users/akash/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dzpknbtessbfrlebffizodpgatsq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/qa/BuildProductsPath/Release-qa-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks
Symlinked...
rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --links --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/DKImagePickerController.framework" "/Users/akash/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dzpknbtessbfrlebffizodpgatsq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/qa/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Runner.app/Frameworks"
building file list ... rsync: link_stat "/Users/akash/Mobile/ios/../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/DKImagePickerController.framework" failed: No such file or directory (2)
done

sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/aaefcfd1-5c95-11ed-8734-2e32217d8374/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

mkdir -p /Users/akash/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dzpknbtessbfrlebffizodpgatsq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/qa/BuildProductsPath/Release-qa-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks

Symlinked...

rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --links --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/DKImagePickerController.framework" "/Users/akash/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dzpknbtessbfrlebffizodpgatsq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/qa/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Runner.app/Frameworks"

building file list ... rsync: link_stat "/Users/akash/Mobile/ios/../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/DKImagePickerController.framework" failed: No such file or directory (2)

done



sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec

total size is 0  speedup is 0.00

rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/aaefcfd1-5c95-11ed-8734-2e32217d8374/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]

Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I tried to clean project, clear pod caches and restart xcode and system.

Nothing helps

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting this answer for future reference.
Open the project in Visual studio code or Android Studio. Follow the path
**iOS/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh**
Replace source="$(readlink "${source}")" with source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"

```
if [ -L "${source}" ]; then
    echo "Symlinked..."
    source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"
fi
```